# Rspec use application controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have method in my `application controller` and want to use it everywhere
 in my integration specs.

I don't want to add it method in every spec

Currently i use

```
 allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:set_seo).and_return('seo_text')
```

but it is inconvenient.

What should i do for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Rspec config you can configure a before and after block for :

> before suite
>
> before all
>
> before each
>
> after each
>
> after all
>
> after suite

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-2/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks

In that order.

I would suggest:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
     allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:set_seo).and_return('seo_text')
  end
end
```

Edit:

It appears that `before(:suite)` can cause problems.

If it doesn't work for you use `before(:each)`

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `spec_helper_integration` file and put functionality specific to integration specs in there.

You should already have `require 'rails_helper'` at the top of all your specs. At the top of your integration specs put:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'spec_helper_integration'
```

Then create a `spec_helper_integration.rb` file in the same folder as your `rails_helper.rb` file.

spec_helper_integration:

```
#I'm taking a guesstimate as to your integration spec configuration, but it's
#likely something like the following line:

#don't also have this in your spec_helper or rails_helper files:
require 'capybara/rails'

#configure your integration specs:
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
    allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:set_seo).and_return('seo_text')
  end
end
```

It's good practice to isolate code to where it is required only; by doing this, your ApplicationController method stubbing is only activated during the running of your integration specs and not your other specs, such as unit or controller specs, for example.

Moving forward, any further integration-spec-specific code should only be put in your spec_helper_integration file, too.